# Xamarin IOS: SIGSEGV while executing native code

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I 'm working on my first xamarin ios application that displays images in a UICollectionView hosted in a UITabBarController. The initial view is a normal view without TabBarController. A button on the initial view loads a new view (UITabBarController) that displays the images in the UICollectionView. Things we working fine and then I updated Mac OS to Sierra, XCode to version 8.3.2 and the application started crashing every time when I seque from the initial controller to the (UITabBarController) view that displays the images in the UICollectionView.

The following is the exception I get in the Application output window

> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.958 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical: Stacktrace:
>
> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.958 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>    <0xffffffff> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.958 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375]
>   critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   Foundation.NSObject.xamarin_release_managed_ref
>   (intptr,Foundation.NSObject) <0x00007> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.958
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>   Foundation.NSObject.ReleaseManagedRef () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:208
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>   Foundation.NSObject/NSObject_Disposer.Drain (Foundation.NSObject)
>   [0x00062] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:784
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in
>   <2f4074c3120b4d80802e10af84b67d41#2892ED79-E936-4F04-126B-3B9FB0CB5554>:0
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>    <0xffffffff> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375]
>   critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>   <0x00007> 2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>   UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.959 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at
>   MyIOSApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in
>   /Users/ETI-MAC3/Documents/Apps/p9Tech/Xamarin/iOSApp/MyIOSApp/MyIOSApp/Main.cs:12
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.960 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in
>   <2f4074c3120b4d80802e10af84b67d41#2892ED79-E936-4F04-126B-3B9FB0CB5554>:0
>   2017-06-06 19:32:50.960 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  Native
>   stacktrace:
>
> 2017-06-06 19:32:51.014 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  0
>   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010400d920
>   mono_handle_native_crash + 260 2017-06-06 19:32:51.014
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x00000001040193d4 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 316 2017-06-06
>   19:32:51.014 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:     2
>   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018509b348 _sigtramp + 52
>   2017-06-06 19:32:51.014 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  3
>   libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x0000000104318b94
>   xamarin_release_managed_ref + 208 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  4   libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib
>   0x00000001023ba968
>   wrapper_managed_to_native_Foundation_NSObject_xamarin_release_managed_ref_intptr_Foundation_NSObject
>   + 104 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:    5   libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x00000001023bad48
>   Foundation_NSObject_ReleaseManagedRef + 24 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  6   libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib
>   0x00000001023bdf88
>   Foundation_NSObject_NSObject_Disposer_Drain_Foundation_NSObject + 312
>   2017-06-06 19:32:51.015 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  7
>   libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x00000001004ef574
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 244 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:    8   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010401c4fc
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 836 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  9   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x0000000104096fe4 do_runtime_invoke + 112 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  10  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x0000000104096f40 mono_runtime_invoke + 208 2017-06-06 19:32:51.015
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  11  MyIOSApp
>   0x000000010005eebc
>   _ZL32native_to_managed_trampoline_112P11objc_objectP13objc_selectorPP11_MonoMethodP8NSObjectj
>   + 376 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:    12  MyIOSApp                           0x000000010005ed38
>   +[**NSObject_Disposer drain:] + 60 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:   13  Foundation
>
>   0x0000000186af26ec  + 340 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  14  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000185fba278  + 24 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  15  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000185fb9bc0  + 524 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  16  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000185fb77c0  + 804 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  17  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000185ee6048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  18  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x0000000187969198 GSEventRunModal + 180 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  19  UIKit
>
>   0x000000018bec0628  + 684 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  20  UIKit
>
>   0x000000018bebb360 UIApplicationMain + 208 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  21  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib
>
>   0x0000000102430d34
>   wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr
>   + 340 2017-06-06 19:32:51.016 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:    22  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x00000001023d3b0c
>   UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 44 2017-06-06
>   19:32:51.017 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:     23 
>   libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x00000001023d3acc
>   UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 172 2017-06-06
>   19:32:51.017 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:     24 
>   libMyIOSApp.exe.dylib              0x0000000100145330
>   MyIOSApp_Application_Main_string** + 128 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  25  libmscorlib.dll.dylib
>   0x00000001004ef574
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 244 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017 MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:    26  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010401c4fc
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 836 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  27  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x0000000104096fe4 do_runtime_invoke + 112 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  28  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x000000010409a208 do_exec_main_checked + 152 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  29  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x0000000104000134 mono_jit_exec + 268 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  30  libxamarin-debug.dylib
>   0x0000000104325804 xamarin_main + 2148 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  31  MyIOSApp
>   0x0000000100075454 main + 96 2017-06-06 19:32:51.017
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical:  32  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000184ec85b8  + 4 2017-06-06 19:32:51.018
>   MyIOSApp[6085:1639375] critical: 
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.

I have uploaded the Symbolicated file [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsLgtWVb3LZ0gWFkST3XW1oZbxM0). Can you please verify and let me know what is causing this issue.

**UPDATED:**

Below is the prepare seque code of the main view:

public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

```
    List<UIViewController> visibleViewControllers = new List<UIViewController>();

    try
    {
        var tabBarViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as UITabBarController;
        var similarImagesViewController = tabBarViewController.ViewControllers[0] as SimilarImagesViewController;
        similarImagesViewController.SimilarImages = myIOSApp.SimilarImages;
        if (myIOSApp.SimilarImages.Count > 0)
        {
            visibleViewControllers.Add(similarImagesViewController);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myIOSApp.WikiLink))
        {
            var wikiViewController = tabBarViewController.ViewControllers[1] as WikiViewController;
            wikiViewController.WikiLink = myIOSApp.WikiLink;
            visibleViewControllers.Add(wikiViewController);
        }
        ((TabBarViewController)tabBarViewController).VisibleViewControllers = visibleViewControllers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AlertViewController.PresentOKAlert("My IOS App", ex.Message, this);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for TabBarViewController class:

```
public partial class TabBarViewController : UITabBarController
    {
        public List<UIViewController> VisibleViewControllers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public TabBarViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            SetViewControllers(VisibleViewControllers.ToArray(), true);
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for SimilarImagesViewController

```
public partial class SimilarImagesViewController : BaseUIViewController
    {
        private static SimilarImagesSource _SimilarImagesSource;

        public List<Models.Image> SimilarImages
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public SimilarImagesViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            try
            {
                Title = "Similar Images";
                _SimilarImagesSource = new SimilarImagesSource(SimilarImages);
                collView.Source = _SimilarImagesSource;
                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    collView.ReloadData()
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AlertViewController.PresentOKAlert("MyIOSApp", ex.Message, this);
            }
        }
    }
```

And below is the Source code for the UICollectionView source

```
public class SimilarImagesSource : UICollectionViewSource, IUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    {
        public SimilarImagesSource(List<Image> similarImages)
        {
            Rows = similarImages;
        }

        public List<Image> Rows { get; private set; }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return Rows.Count;
        }

        [Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:")]
        public CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UIImage image = GetUIImageFromBase64String(Rows[indexPath.Row].ImageString);
            var cgSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
            image.Dispose();
            return cgSize;
        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (ImageCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(ImageCell.Id, indexPath);
            cell.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            var imageView = new UIImageView(GetUIImageFromBase64String(Rows[indexPath.Row].ImageString));
            cell.AddSubview (imageView);
            return cell;
        }

        private UIImage GetUIImageFromBase64String(string imageString)
        {
            if (imageString.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
            {
                return LoadImage(imageString);
            }

            var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
            var imageData = NSData.FromArray(imageBytes);
            var uiImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);

            return uiImage;
        }

        public UIImage LoadImage(string imageUrl)
        {
            byte[] contents;

            using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Task<byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);

                // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
                contents = contentsTask.Result;
            }

            // load from bytes
            return UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(contents));
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: I recall having a similar issue and it was because the images for the tab bar items were not in the resources folder, it wouldn't accept a bundle path. Also the stack trace is useful, but it'd make things easier to see your code.

Comment: Hi Digitalsa1nt, I have edited my question and added the code as requested. The application crashes after the PrepareForSeque code and before showing the SimilarImagesViewController view. Please let me know if any other information is required.